# Did Galadriel wake up a lot of people by her shouting at the One Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring, galadriel

In the movie *The Fellowship of the Ring*, after Frodo offers the One Ring to Galadriel, she puts on a display of power and shouts very loudly at the One Ring. I have always wondered if her loud shouting had woken up a lot of Elves in the area.

Did Galadriel wake up a lot of people by her shouting at the One Ring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's unlikely. The event (at least in the novel) takes place in relative seclusion. First she leads the hobbits up a path away from the settlement, then into an enclosed garden behind a tall hedge and then they travel to the bottom of a long hollow within that enclosure.

> Turning aside, she led them toward the southern slopes of the hill of Caras Galadhon, and **passing through a high green hedge they came into an enclosed garden.** No trees grew there, and it lay open to the sky. The evening star had risen and was shining with white fire above the western woods. **Down a long flight of steps the Lady went into a deep green hollow,** through which ran murmuring the silver stream that issued from the fountain on the hill. At the bottom, upon a low pedestal carved like a branching tree, stood a basin of silver. wide and shallow, and beside it stood a silver ewer.
>
> <sub><sup>Fellowship of the Ring: Chapter 7 - The Mirror of Galadriel</sup></sub>

Galadriel's shouting only lasted a few seconds after which there was silence and no commotion from outside the garden.

> ... All shall love me and despair! '
>
> She lifted up her hand and from the ring that she wore there issued a great light that illuminated her alone and left all else dark. She stood before Frodo seeming now tall beyond measurement, and beautiful beyond enduring, terrible and worshipful. Then she let her hand fall, and the light faded, and suddenly she laughed again, and lo! she was shrunken: a slender elf-woman, clad in simple white, whose gentle voice was soft and sad.
>
> 'I pass the test,' she said. `I will diminish, and go into the West and remain Galadriel.'
>
> **They stood for a long while in silence.** At length the Lady spoke again. 'Let us return!' she said. `In the morning you must depart for now we have chosen, and the tides of fate are flowing.'

Comment: I was under the impression that she had led Frodo down to the base of the tree that her house was built on and that other Elves lived in houses built on trees nearby to hers. Since Elves have good hearing, I was thinking that a lot of them would have likely been woken up by her loud shouting.